# POI Servlet Check Null no working

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

There are certain result that run in my program and it will be display in excel. Unfortunately the problem i facing was the cell can't set other value if there is null value detected. Error message i get is java null pointer.

```
  Date invalid_dt=servPerfTracking.getInvalid_d();   
    cell=row.createCell(10);                
            if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("Apple");
                log.debug("invalid date is null");
            }else if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){    

                cell=row.createCell(10);
                cell.setCellValue(invalid_dt);
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
                log.debug("invalid date is not equal to null");
            }
```

Comment: You appear to be creating a fresh new cell, then checking the type of it. How do you expect this to ever give you a different answer?

Comment: The description of your problem is really vague. It's really hard to answer your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

## What you are actually doing

First, you are creating a **new and empty** cell. After that, you are checking the type of that cell.

By definition, the type of newly created cells is `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.

## What you should do

Use the method [`row.getCell(int columnNumber)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int)) to receive the actual cell of the current row for the specified column number.

### Example

```
Date invalid_dt = servPerfTracking.getInvalid_d();

cell = row.getCell(10, Row.RETURN_NULL_AS_BLANK);                
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    cell.setCellValue("Apple");
    log.debug("invalid date is null");
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {    
    cell.setCellValue(invalid_dt);
    cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
    log.debug("invalid date is not equal to null");
}
```

**Tip**: You don't need to call [`cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType(int)) because it will be implicitly set by the method `cell.setCellValue("Apple")`.

> `void setCellType(int cellType)`
>   Set the cells type (numeric, formula or string).
>   If the cell currently contains a value, the value will be converted to match the new type, if possible.

Comment: You need to either add a `if (cell == null)` check near the start, or change your code to be `cell = row.getCell(10,Row.RETURN_NULL_AS_BLANK)` (using a Missing Cell Policy), otherwise it'll NPE on any row without a value in that column

Comment: @winklerrr: i still get the java null pointer error message. I did try this way before. Isn't because i didn't set any value inside?

Comment: A cell can also contain a `null` value (if that's the case the cell type is set to blank)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what i did for resolve it was:

```
 String invalid_dt=""; 
 if(servPerfTracking.getInvalid_d()!=null)
 invalid_dt=servPerfTracking.getInvalid_d().toString(); 
 cell = row.createCell(10); 
 cell.setCellValue(invalid_dt);
 cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
```